# mongoose aggregate using $exists in $cond

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to `$project` if a field exists, but not it's value, using `mongoose` `model` `aggregate` query.
If it was possible using `$exists` in `$cond`, it would have looked something like this:

```
$project: {
    b: {
        $cond: {
            if    : {$exists: ['$b', true]},
            then  : true,
            else  : false
        }
    }
}
```

But, I have to use a `boolean` expression in the `$cond` operator.
In the MongoDB shell, I can do something similar with:

```
{$eq: ['$b', undefined]}
```

and it yields the expected results, but with `mongoose` model `aggregate` for some reason, it always results with `true`.

for example, if I have the following documents:

```
{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
},
{
    "a" : 1
}
```

I need the following results:

```
{
    "b": true
},
{
    "b": false
}
```

How can I do something like that with `mongoose`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`$exists` not supported in `aggregate` query of **MongoDB**. So in `aggregate` query instead of `$exists` can use `$ifNull`.

syntax:

```
{ $ifNull: [ <expression>, <replacement-expression-if-null> ] }
```

[for more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

**Updated:**

to get `b` value as `true` or `false` can try this query

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            b: { 
                $cond: [
                    {$ifNull: ['$b', false]}, // if
                    true, // then
                    false // else
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Explanation:**

```
b = $cond: [ 'if condition satisfied', 'then true', 'else false' ];
```

where `condition = {$ifNull: ['$b', false]}`
 Here if `$b` not exist then `condition = false` otherwise `condition = true`.

so if `condition = true` then return *then result* that means `b = true`
if `condition = false` then return *else result* means `b = false`

Comment: I can't use `$ifNull` because I don't want to project the field's value, only if it exists or not. in case `$ifNull` returns false, it will project the value.

Comment: actually what is your goal can you add an example in your question section  to be more clear @TomG

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @ShaishabRoy hi can you explain when the condition is getting "true" and why?
tried the code and I get "true" when the field exists

Comment: @DaNLtR I have added an explanation so you may clear now

Comment: @ShaishabRoy checked the documentation, $ifNull will return false if not exists which means condition = false, thank you!!

Comment: This is beautifully explained @ShaishabRoy. It's an elegant way to branch depending on the results of $ifNull.

Answer (score 4):

You could use two `$project` statement for this case and make use of the [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator (Just wont work when `some_field` is set as `false` in which case you can change the inner `false` to something more suitable)

```
[
{
        $project: {
        test: {
            $ifNull: [
                '$some_field',
                false
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        test: {
            $cond: {
                if    : {$eq: ['$test', false]},
                then  : false,
                else  : true
            }
        }
    }
}

])
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but I prefer not adding additional `$project` stage, this is not the only field and condition I'm using.