# mongo $cond with subfields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data in my db (with irrelevant fields removed).

```
{
  "multiclass": {
    "datasetname": {
      "labels": {
        "al": {
          "timestamp": {
            "$date": {
              "$numberLong": "1628689826073"
            }
          },
          "classification": "wrong_ingredient"
        },
        "bob": {
          "timestamp": {
            "$date": {
              "$numberLong": "1628765248010"
            }
          },
          "classification": "wrong_ingredient"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if a document that hasn't been given a label by candice has been given a sufficient number of labels by other labelers. In this case, both al and bob have labeled it, so it should return 2, which is less than 3, so this document should be included.
Here's the query I've written.

```
{
  "multiclass.datasetname.labels.candice": {$exists: false},
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      {
        $cond: {
          if: {"multiclass.datasetname.labels": {$exists: true}},
          then: {$size: {$objectToArray: "$multiclass.datasetname.labels"}},
          else: 0
        }
      },
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

Running this results in the error `FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField.` (which refers the the line `if: {"multiclass.datasetname.labels": {$exists: true}},` and not to the line `"multiclass.datasetname.labels.candice": {$exists: false}`)
I do not know what this error is trying to get across, except perhaps it thinks I'm trying to access an element with dots in it's name, rather than trying to access a field with a subfield with a subfield?

The questions I've seen on SO with related errors, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433120/fieldpath-field-names-may-not-contain-in-group) give a work around for the specific problem, rather than an explanation of *why* it isn't working, which makes it difficult to apply to my situation.

So my question is primarily why can't I use dots inside the $expr, but I can use dots outside it?
If you can answer that question, a solution would also be useful, but it's much more important that I know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542746/mongoose-aggregate-using-exists-in-cond

Comment: Oh my goodness yes. It does indeed solve my problem. It doesn't explain why the way I wanted to do it doesn't work, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I can't use dots in the field path is because it is part of an expression. When a field path is part of an expression it must be prefixed with a `$`. see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-agg-quick-ref-field-paths).

Outside the expression it's fine to use dot notation without the dollar sign. This answers *why* it was wrong, but for a solution on *how* to solve the problem, see the link ISAE left in the comments.